# popup form using JQuery in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, popupwindow

I'm trying to open a contact form as popup like below picture , once user click link or button in asp.net mvc view page

[image]

this is **index.cshtml** viewpage

```
       @{       
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Right_upper_Layout.cshtml";
        }

       <a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="emailDialog" data-dialog-title="contactus" href="~/Home/ContactUs">Contact US</a>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {    
            e.preventDefault();    
            $("<div></div>")    
            .addClass("dialog")    
            .attr("id",$(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))    
            .appendTo("body")    
            .dialog({    
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                modal: true    
            })

            .load(this.href);
        });
    });
</script>


@section Scripts 
{}
```

this is controller

```
    public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        return PartialView("ContactUs");
    }
```

this is **ContactUs.cshtml** page

```
<label for="Name">Name:</label><br />

<input id="Namecontact" name="Name" type="text" /><br />

<label for="email">Email:</label><br />

<input id="emailcontact" name="email" type="text" /><br />

<label for="message">Message:</label><br />

<textarea id="messagecontact" name="message"></textarea>

<input class="close" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

but once I click this **ContactUs** its open new tab not a popup, whats wrong here.

Comment: Try updating your `jquery` file to latest version and check if you have any **console errors** in browser

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I have following [jquery versions](http://i.imgur.com/Or86obr.jpg) which one I should select , this is [my layout file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/6rz98)

Comment: Sound like your scripts are not firing and you just making a redirect to `Home/ContactUs`. Put a `console.log()` statement in your scripts to check its being hit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke put like this `$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) { console.log() ..` then I checked console errors , but non of the error in that view

Comment: You need to put something in side it to display a message which you can check is displayed - `console.log('got here');` And it should be just `$(".openDialog").click(function(e) { ....`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can see following [Console Window in Firebug](http://i.imgur.com/SjGIxxz.jpg) , what can I do here

Comment: Make sure you load `jquery-1.9.1.js` (or a higher version) and that its loaded before all other scripts.

Comment: @StephenMuecke once I change to jquery version `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>` then I cannot go to that `ContactUs` view as previous , but I can see following [console window](http://i.imgur.com/sLShNpA.jpg)

Comment: That suggests `.dialog()` (which I assume is in jquery-ui) is not found. But you need to start learning how to write your code (but I have repeatedly told you that before). Break it down one line at a time and debug your code to determine just where the error is occurring.

Comment: http://amitraya.blogspot.com/2012/09/modal-dialog-form-view-using-jquery.html